# Can a transaction consist only of a read operation?

Tags: sql

Recently I was at an technical interview, the interviewer insisted that there are no read transactions in SQL. Transactions are only needed to modify data. 
Is it so? Could you please argument your answer? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The interviewer was wrong.
A transaction can consist only of a read operation (and the transaction is significant)

Here is an example for **SQL Server**

> **REPEATABLE READ**
>   Specifies that statements cannot read data that has
>   been modified but not yet committed by other transactions and that **no
>   other transactions can modify data that has been read by the current
>   transaction until the current transaction completes.**
>   [SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
-- setup
create table t (i int);
insert into t(i) values (1);

-- session 1
set transaction isolation level repeatable read
begin transaction
select * from t

-- session 2
update t set i = 2 -- session 2 is blocked until session 1 commits/rollbacks
```

As you can see session 1 is consist only of a read operation and yet the transaction is significant

Here is another example for **Oracle**

> **Transaction-Level Read Consistency**
>   Oracle Database can also provide read consistency to all queries in a transaction, known as
>   transaction-level read consistency. In this case, **each statement in a
>   transaction sees data from the same point in time, which is the time
>   at which the transaction began.**
>   [Data Concurrency and Consistency](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25054_01/server.1111/e25789/consist.htm)

```
-- setup
create table t (i int);
insert into t(i) values (1);

-- session 1
set transaction read only;

-- session 2
update t set i = 2;

-- session 1
select * from t; -- for sesion 1 --> i = 1

-- session 2
update t set i = 3;

-- session 1
select * from t; -- for sesion 1 --> i = 1
commit;

select * from t; -- for sesion 1 --> i = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can mark databases as 'read-only' and still perform transactions on them. Although at that point there is no real point in using a transaction as their guarantees are already enforced by no writes happening... so yes and no